# When does $C(a^i)=C(a^j)$ if $|a|$ is finite?

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for a necessary and sufficient condition for $C(a^i)=C(a^j)$ to hold in a general group G given that $|a|$ is finite and known.

What if $|a|$ is a prime?

Here $C(a)=\{g\in G \;| \;gag^{-1}=a\}$

Comment: Do you want it to hold for all $i,j$ or are you asking for a condition depending on $i,j$ that would imply $C(a^i)=C(a^j)$ for that particular $i,j$?

Comment: @Levent Yes, I am

Comment: I don't think you are answering my question. Do you want it to hold for all $i,j$?